# How to solve this integral using polylogarithms?

Tags: definite-integrals

> Prove that
>   $$I(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{x\ln (1+x)}{1+x^2} \, dx=
> \frac{\pi^2}{96}+\frac{\ln(2)^2}{8}.$$

I tried this and broke it in a form where I can use 2nd order polylogarithm but could not proceed.
[This answer is confirmed by Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+0+to+1+xln(1%2Bx)%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{I \equiv
> \int_{0}^{1}{x\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x =
> {\phantom{^{2}}\pi^{2} \over 96} + {\ln^{2}\pars{2} \over 8}:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
I & \equiv
\int_{0}^{1}{x\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x =
\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x - \ic}\,\dd x =
\Re\int_{-\ic}^{1 - \ic}{\ln\pars{1 + \ic + x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\bracks{\ln\pars{1 + \ic}\int_{-\ic}^{1 - \ic}{\dd x \over x} +
\int_{-\ic}^{1 - \ic}\ln\pars{1 - {x \over -1 - \ic}}\,{\dd x \over x}}
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\bracks{\ln\pars{1 + \ic}\ln\pars{1 - \ic} - \ln\pars{1 + \ic}\ln\pars{-\ic} +
\int_{-\ic/\pars{-1 - \ic}}^{\pars{1 - \ic}/\pars{-1 - \ic}}
{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x}
\\[1cm] & =
\overbrace{\verts{\ln\pars{1 + \ic}}^{2}}
^{\ds{{\phantom{^{2}}\pi^{2} \over 16} + {\ln^{2}\pars{2} \over 4}}}\ -\
{\pi \over 2}\,\
\overbrace{\Im\ln\pars{1 + \ic}}^{\ds{\pi \over 4}}\ -\
\underbrace{\overbrace{\Re\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\ic}}
^{\ds{\Re\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{n} \over n^{2}} =
-\,{1 \over 8}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}}}}
_{\ds{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 48}}}\
+\
\Re\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 24} + {\ln^{2}\pars{2} \over 4} +
{1 \over 2}\braces{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic} +
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 - \bracks{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic}}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> The last *polyLogarithm* expression can be evaluated with
>   [Euler Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm).

Namely,
\begin{align}
&{1 \over 2}\braces{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic} +
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 - \bracks{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\bracks{{\phantom{^{2}}\pi^{2} \over 6}
- \ln\pars{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic}
\ln\pars{{1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2}\,\ic}} =
{\pi^{2} \over 12} -
{1 \over 2}\verts{\ln\pars{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic}}^{2}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pi^{2} \over 12} -
{1 \over 2}\verts{-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2} + {\pi \over 4}\,\ic}^{2} =
{5\pi^{2} \over 96} - {\ln^{2}\pars{2} \over 8}
\end{align}

---

Expression \eqref{1} is reduced to:
$$
I  \equiv
\int_{0}^{1}{x\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x =
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 24} + {\ln^{2}\pars{2} \over 4} +
\bracks{{5\pi^{2} \over 96} - {\ln^{2}\pars{2} \over 8}} =
\bbx{{\phantom{^{2}}\pi^{2} \over 96} + {\ln^{2}\pars{2} \over 8}}
$$

Comment: thanks felix marin

Comment: @Apollo15 You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

For $t>0$, let
$$I(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{x\ln (1+tx)}{1+x^2} \, dx$$
then, we have that
$$I'(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(1+tx)(1+x^2)} \, dx=
\frac{4\ln(1+t)+2\ln(2)t^2-\pi t}{4t(1+t^2)}
$$
By noting that $I(0^+)=0$, integrate with respect $t$ in order to compute $I(1)$
$$I(1)=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}dt-I(1)+\frac{\ln(2)}{2}\int_0^1\frac{t}{1+t^2}dt-\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$$
and we obtain
$$2I(1)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{\ln(2)^2}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\implies I(1)=\frac{\pi^2}{96}+\frac{\ln(2)^2}{8}.$$

P.S. Note that
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}dt=\int_0^1\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-t)^{n-1}}{n}dt=-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2}=-\mbox{Li}_2(-1)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}.$$

Comment: can u give it in detail as i also tried feynman's technique

Comment: @Apollo15 Some details are given in the edited answer.